# What is a parameterization and specifically, of this given one in 3D?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I'm not sure how to ask this properly. But I can't find a general and simple understanding of what a parameterization is for a vector and its components. I have an example if it could help you explain better:

the line segment from (0,0,2) to (0,0,5)

Answer: **r**(t)= < 0, 0, t > for ∈ [2, 5]

How do I start with the line given the two points into the final answer? Also a short and simple explanation of parameterization would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, a parameterization of the line segment from $(0,0,2)$ to $(0,0,5)$ would be:

First, choose a starting point. Because it is from $(0,0,2)$ to $(0,0,5)$, the starting point is $(0,0,2)$. Then subtract the coordinates of the starting point from $(0,0,5)$. This is $(0,0,3)$. This is your direction vector. Then the parametrization would simply be $<0,0,2> + t<0,0,3>$ or $<0,0,2+3t>$, where $t$ is an element from $0$ to $1$, inclusive.

Parametrization, in general, is a way to express two variables in terms of a third variable. Parametrization is also used to represent equations and vectors with three variables in terms of two variables. Hope this helps!

Comment: Just one concern, how come the answer is < 0, 0, t > but you got 
< 0, 0 , 2+3 t> ?
But thank you for your answer, it really helped.

Comment: Hi! Glad it helped. We have different answers because my answer is when t  goes from 0 to 1. However, the answer you provided is when t goes from 2 to 5. Either answer is correct as long as the domain is specified. Thanks for asking, I'll make sure to specify that in my answer.

Comment: Great! One last thing, so our answers can't be interchangeable if the domains were to remain the same? Or another way of saying it, how does changing the domain from 0 to 1, to 2 to 5, change the vector <0, 0, 2+3t> into <0, 0, t>?

Comment: Imagine plugging in all values from t = 0 to t = 1 in <0, 0, 2+3t>. Then, you should get every point in the line from (0, 0, 2) to (0, 0, 5). Then imagine plugging in all values from t = 2 to t = 5 in <0, 0, t>. Then, you should get every point in the line from (0, 0, 2) to (0, 0, 5). Changing the domains for either would give us less or more points than the question asks for.